# How to create views in SwiftUI using collect

Tags: swift, swiftui, reactive-programming, combine

I am trying to figure out a way to insert multiple arrays of views in a VStack in SwiftUI using `collect()` operator.

```
struct ChatsTab: View {
    var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"].publisher.collect(2).sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in
                // Do nothing on completion
            }) { (stringArray) in
                HStack {
                    Text(stringArray[0])
                    Text(stringArray[1])
                }
            }
        .store(in: &subscriptions)
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this below error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '()' to closure result type '_'
```

I want to do this with `collect` only so I can add my text views in pair. I know I have other options but I want to get it done with `collect` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to rearrange things. The real issue is not the `collect`, the issue is that you're trying to execute arbitrary code inside the `VStack`. The `VStack` is a function builder and between it's curly braces goes a list of views and possibly some basic `if` logic only. Not arbitrary code, like the kind you include in a regular function. 
So if you take the publisher code out of the VStack it will compile. Where you put it is up to you, you can have it in `init()`, called from another function, or int `didAppear` view modifier (just not inside the VStack directly).

A second issue is that the collect will publish another array (one of length 2). You will essentially end up with an array of String arrays (or you can just consume them as they are published and not keep them around, depending on what you are trying to do). You can also use the simpler version of `sink` since the `Error` of the publisher here is `Never`. Anyway here is something incorporating the above changes:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

struct ContentView: View {

  @State var stringArrays: [[String]] = []

    var body: some View {
      ForEach(stringArrays, id: \.self) { stringArray in
        HStack {
          Text(stringArray.count > 0 ? stringArray[0] : "")
          Text(stringArray.count > 1 ? stringArray[1] : "")
        }
      }.onAppear() {
        ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"].publisher
          .collect(2)
          .sink(receiveValue: { (stringArray) in
            self.stringArrays.append(stringArray)
          }).store(in: &subscriptions)
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: It can be simplified further, without sink, using assign:to, I think

Comment: You could use assign, but since here I'm appending not overwriting, you would have to have a second collect before you assign again, like `.collect().assign(to: \ContentView.stringArrays, on: self)`. Also looking at my example, it's not as clear as it could be. The thing to remember is that that whole `ForEach` view, including the `onAppear` modifier is one view. Arbitrary code can be in the `onAppear` because its argument is a closure.